# Running Codenet on a Commodore 64 Emulator

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, network

I finally managed to get basic networking stuff working on VICE, thanks to another [thread](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17749/running-warpcopy64-on-an-emulator) on Retrocomputing. I'm now wondering how to setup a [Codenet](http://wiki.icomp.de/wiki/Codenet) server emulation.

I was able to identify four Codenet implementations.

1. The original firmware of [RR-Net](http://wiki.icomp.de/wiki/RR-Net) MK3,
2. the [alternative](https://svn.icomp.de/svn/rrnetmk3/trunk/) firmware for RR-Net MK3,
3. the [FinalReplay](http://www.oxyron.de/html/freplay.html) image for the [Retro Replay](http://wiki.icomp.de/wiki/Retro_Replay) and
4. the [Turbo Action](https://www.dekadence64.org/prodstools.html) image for the  Retro Replay.

I'm unable to locate an image of the original firmware. I guess it is only shipped with the hardware.

The alternative firmware is available online. The archive contains a disk image with a tool used for flashing the hardware. I believe I could setup the VICE RR-Net Mk3 emulation to extract the image from the flash utility and then use the VICE *cartconv* utility to convert the image into a cart. However, I did not yet go through the trouble of doing all that. Perhaps that is worth trying.

Setting up Final Replay seemed a bit easier. I first configured IP addresses with the included setip.exe. I then converted the raw image to a crt image with `cartconv -t rr -i tfr08.bin -o tfr08.crt`. After performing a *smart attach* in VICE the Final Replay banner was displayed. The included `INFO` command displayed the configuration correctly. I then run the `CODENET` command to start the server and got a blinking text `READY.`. I wonder if this the intended behavior when the server is waiting for instructions. However, I was unable to get a response from the server by sending hand crafted Codenet instructions.

I'm able to start Turbo Action by using cartconv to convert the raw image in similar manner to Final Replay. I then press F7 to get into the command prompt. At this point I can run command `HELP` to list Turbo Action commands. The networking and Codenet related commands `CONF` and `CODENET` are listed but but VICE crashes with `Main CPU: Jam` if I try to execute either one of them.

Comment: So... what's the question you're asking us to answer?

Comment: How to get any Codenet server to work on any C64 emulator

Comment: I'm no expert on judging these things, but that sounds like it might be too broad a question for the StackExchange Q&A format. Answers aren't supposed to be the kind of full-blown tutorials you'd make a blog post about.